# Python Reverse an indexed list from a tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples, reverse

I have a tuple that prints out:

```
('1234556', '2', 'G400', ['Simpson', 'Homer', 'Bartholomew'], 'Simpson, Bartholomew Homer')
```

I now need code to print out the items from the list within the tuple (index 3) however instead of printing

```
['Simpson', 'Homer', 'Bartholomew']
```

I need it to print
Bartholomew Homer Simpson

my current code is:

```
regNo=int(input("Enter the student registration number: "))
        regNo=str(regNo)
        for i in lst:
            if i[0] == regNo:
                print(i[3])
```

Meaning it's printing out:

```
['Simpson', 'Homer', 'Bartholomew']
```

I tried a reverse function like print(reversed(i[3])) but that didn't work. How would i go across doing this? In the end i need to get it out of a list and print in reversed order

Comment: What do you mean by "that didn't work"?

Comment: Why do you covert your input to a integer then convert it right back to a string?

Comment: by "that didn't work" you get results like `<reversed object at 0x0000000003ED4F60>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reverse a list in python you can use `lst[::-1]` (where `lst` is the name of the variable you have the list in).

In your code you can use:

```
regNo=int(input("Enter the student registration number: "))
regNo=str(regNo)
for i in lst:
    if i[0] == regNo:
        print(" ".join(i[3][::-1]))
```

Comment: Although this would work, it's printing out like so `['Bartholomew', 'Homer', 'Simpson']` so it has reversed but its still within this list as seperate items, how would i remove the brackets and the '

Comment: This wasn't really the question, but you can use `print(" ".join(i[3][::-1]))` instead :)

Comment: Perfect! i was thinking about splitting it then joining after but it seems i didn't need to

Answer (score 1):

To reverse a list: try this:

```
i[3][::-1]
```

Example:

```
a= [1,2,3]
a[::-1]
Out[10]: [3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `reversed` you will receive a `list_reverseiterator` object. So if you print it you will get `<list_reverseiterator object at 0x01321CB0>`.

You would have to make a list from it `print(list(reversed(i[3])))`. I would recommend to use `print(i[3][::-1])` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand what you mean.

If you want to reverse a list, use `list.reverse`.

To combine the `str` inside the list, use `' '.join(<your list>)`.

Answer (score 0):

Printing the result of `reversed` does not work because `reversed` returns an iterator, not a list. However, the `join` method accepts an iterator, so it would work to concatenate the elements in the list to form the text you want to print.

```
reversed_iter = reversed(i[3])
result = ' '.join(reversed_iter)
print(result)

>> Bartholomew Homer Simpson
```